# Why was React 360 formerly React VR deprecated/stopped?

Tags: facebook, deprecated, oculus, react-360

I've been searching the internet for a couple of hours and couldn't find anything related. So far, I just found that the [GitHub project](https://github.com/facebookarchive/react-360) is archived. Also, there are several [posts](https://developer.oculus.com/blog/react-360-replaces-react-vr-for-streamlined-development-focus/) about the rebranding made in 2018, but none mention that they will stop working on it. They are even keeping the old [React VR Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/videos/f8-2017/react-vr-build-amazing-vr-experiences-using-react/).

So, what happened to it?

Answer (score -1):

It seems like this is the case.  You can see all of the currently supported development technologies [here](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/).  Two of these are Unity and Unreal.  Just click on the computer icon to see the other technologies.  I looked through all of the options and did not see React mentioned anywhere.

Comment: Thanks, TaxExprez. However, it does not answer the question of why it was stopped. That reaffirms that it doesn't have any support anymore, tho.